# php connection to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a website (www.calendariocubano.org) hosted in Godaddy.com, and I have a mysql database server at home.

I would like to make all the registration process in my database home server, but I can't make the connection.

Below is the function used to connect. Before put the database at home, I have it at Goddady and it works.

```
function doDB() {
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("50.250.86.124","admin","xxxxxxxxxxxx","calendariocubano"); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having some component at your home pegs the website availability to your home server availability. I wouldn't recommend it.

But the most likely reason why you can't connect is, your home router may be blocking the mysql port. Go to the firewall settings on your router and allow mysql port(default usually is 3306) and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I opened all ports in the router and the connection issues continues

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'p3nlhg1140.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net' (using password: YES) in /home/content/45/12071445/html/registration1.php on line 5
Connect failed: Access denied for user 'admin'@'p3nlhg1140.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net' (using password: YES)

Comment: Looks like you have not created the user in your home server. Try something like this.... create user '<<username>>'@'%%' identified by '<<password>>'; <br><br>
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '<<username>>'@'%%'; <br><br>
flush privileges;

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is the first time that I ask a question online and it was successful. Right now, I can connect to my home database server.